# How do you force Jenkins (via Blue Ocean) to pull from GitHub?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-blueocean

I've got this interface:

[image]

but can't see how you force Jenkins to do a pull from github and do another build.

Top circular icon is: Rerun
Bottom is: Restart Deploy

Neither do a pull.

From the pipeline screen I see:

[image]

the circular icon to the right is `Rerun`.

The top right pointing icon is `Go to Classic`.

Answer (score 1):

If you switch to the "Branches" tab and hover over one of the entries, you can click on "Start". I think that in this case it will pull first, at least most of the time (?, Blue Ocean seems to be a little buggy in this respect). You could also switch to Classic and rerun from there.